# Bash Replace Double Lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to iterate through a file, look for occurrences of two empty lines in a row, and delete one empty line so that there is only one empty line --> and then save the file. How can I do this with bash, or other script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-s` option to `cat` does this:

> -s, --squeeze-blank
>
> suppress repeated empty output lines

So:

```
cat -s file > file.new
mv file.new file
```

If this isn't filtering out all blank lines, they may not be truly empty, there may be <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters. You can turn these into empty lines with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^\s+$//' file | cat -s > file.new
```

Comment: I'm noticing with large files, it doesn't catch all of the occurrences. Thoughts?

Comment: See the addition of `sed`

Answer (score 2):

Normal `cat` may not have the `-s` option, so you can also use `sed`:

```
sed -i '/./,/^$/!d' file
```